# Elasticsearch Unicast Weird Behavior in Clustering

Tags: elasticsearch, unicast

I have two nodes each of which forms a cluster (with one empty node).

```
0.0.0.0:9200 (elasticsearch)
0.0.0.0:9201 (test-1)
```

Node at 9200 is in cluster `elasticsearch` (maybe default `cluster.name`). Node at 9201 is in cluster `test-1`. (Additionally, important or not, I bind `network.host`s of both nodes to 0.0.0.0)

I want to join a new node to `test-1`.  When I leave `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` setting commented out alone, the new node is successfully joined to `test-1`. However, When I set it something else, e.g., `["0.0.0.0"]` or `["127.0.1"]`, it is failed to join...

Joining a new node to `elasticsearch` has no problem. `["0.0.0.0"]`, `["127.0.1"]` and `["IP"]` all worked well. (But `["0.0.0.0", "ANOTHER-IP"]` failed... Please answer about this as well if possible...)

What causes this joining issue? Have anybody experienced problems like this?

Comment: Which version on ElasticSearch are you using?

Comment: They are all elasticsearch-6.4.0. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` should have the IPs of all the nodes joining the cluster. Do this for all the nodes in the cluster and use IPs not 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1.

As your new node is trying to join the `test-1` cluster you can try to change the port of the new node to 9201 and see if it joins.

The minimal things required to form a cluster:

1. Same `cluster.name`
2. Put different `node.name`
3. `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` - IPs of all the nodes in the cluster.

`gateway.recover_after_nodes` and `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` - comment these lines if they are not already so for all the nodes of the cluster.

Lastly check your firewall settings and disable the firewall if necessary. Check if the nodes can talk to each other.

Comment: Is `2.` required? Anyway, I will try as you say!

Comment: I have tried running a cluster without specifying node names. Its better to have different ones, especially as there are some issues. Hope this solves the problem.